# Do tests "remember"? independency

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I guess the title might be a bit confusing, hopefully you'll understand my question after the explanation.

I want to write a JUnit test class in java. I created an empty list in the constructor. Let's say one test method adds an element to that list and returns true if there is 1 element in that list. Another test method just returns true if the list is empty. Do the tests work independently from each other?

Comment: How did you define the list that both tests are using?

Comment: Tests *should* work independently. You could always keep some state inside the test class itself but it's better to avoid tests that depend on each other. It is not always guaranteed that tests run in the same order you define them.

Comment: Please post the whole JUnit code so we can see exactly what you mean.

Comment: Depends on how you write your tests and the testing framework you're using. Unit tests should not share state between each other, as that defeats the purpose of unit tests. JUnit Jupiter (i.e., JUnit 5) makes it difficult to accidentally share state between tests. For instance, unless configured otherwise, JUnit Jupiter will create a _new_ instance of the test class for every test method executed. But if you really wanted to (you should typically not want to), you can write the tests to share state.

Comment: I suppose it also depends on how you wrote the code being tested. If you save state in static variables, and don't clean up after a test, then it will exist between tests because that's how static works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the test framework, version, and settings.

In JUnit 4, a single instance of a class is used to run all tests in the class. That means that yes, the tests remember.

In JUnit 5, by default a new instance is created for every test. That includes parameterized tests - that's the reason why (by default) argument factory methods need to be static, as there is no instance yet to provide the arguments.
You can use `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)` to change the behaviour to again use a single instance for all tests.

---

As QBrute said in a comment, tests *should* work independently. That means that if your test class maintains state, that state should be reset. JUnit 5 uses `@BeforeEach` and `@AfterEach` for that. Preferably use `@BeforeEach`, because then a failure in the state-reset will not lead to another test failing.

So:

```
@BeforeEach
void initializeList() {
    myList = new ArrayList<>();
    // now every test has its own fresh list
}
```